# Control M timefrom Dependency removal

Tags: dependencies, controls, scheduling

I want to remove TIMEFROM="HH:MM" and TIMETO=">" dependency from my control M job and wants to only trigger job once predecessor job completed. I have put INCOND criteria in the job defination. How should I remove TIMETO dependency and trigger only on predecessor job completion? Kindly advise. I have put  and expects job to only trigger when  job is completed.